# Can't get dialyzer to work with evm

Tags: erlang, dialyzer, evm

I have `erlang 17.5` installed in /usr/local/lib.  `evm` considers that my "system" install.  After installing evm, I downloaded `erlang 19.2`, and I can switch back and forth between my two versions of erlang using:

```
$ evm system (erlang 17.5)

$ evm use 19.2  (erlang 19.2)
```

I was able to set up dialyzer with erlang 17.5, but when I switch to erlang 19.2 and try to setup dialyzer, here is what happens :

```
~/erlang_programs$ evm use 19.2

~/erlang_programs$ dialyzer
  Checking whether the PLT /Users/7stud/.dialyzer_plt is up-to-date... no
    (the PLT /Users/7stud/.dialyzer_plt was built with an old version of Dialyzer)
  Compiling some key modules to native code... done in 0m0.24s
  Rebuilding the information in /Users/7stud/.dialyzer_plt...
dialyzer: Analysis failed with error:
Could not scan the following file(s):
Could not get core Erlang code for: /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-2.4/ebin/timer.beam    
Could not get core Erlang code for: /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-2.4/ebin/sys.beam  
Could not get core Erlang code for: /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-2.4/ebin/supervisor_bridge.beam  
Could not get core Erlang code for: /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-2.4/ebin/supervisor.beam  
Could not get core Erlang code for: /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-2.4/ebin/lists.beam  
Could not get core Erlang code for: /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-2.4/ebin/proc_lib.beam  
Could not get core Erlang code for: /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-2.4/ebin/gen_event.beam 
Could not get core Erlang code for: /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-2.4/ebin/gen_server.beam  
Could not get core Erlang code for: /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-2.4/ebin/array.beam  
Could not get core Erlang code for: /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/kernel-3.2/ebin/seq_trace.beam  
Could not get core Erlang code for: /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/kernel-3.2/ebin/rpc.beam  
Could not get core Erlang code for: /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/kernel-3.2/ebin/gen_udp.beam  
Could not get core Erlang code for: /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/kernel-3.2/ebin/gen_tcp.beam  
Could not get core Erlang code for: /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/kernel-3.2/ebin/file.beam  
Could not get core Erlang code for: /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/kernel-3.2/ebin/disk_log.beam  
Could not get core Erlang code for: /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/kernel-3.2/ebin/code.beam  
Could not get core Erlang code for: /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/kernel-3.2/ebin/application.beam  
Could not get core Erlang code for: /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/erts-6.4/ebin/erlang.beam
        Last messages in the log cache:
          Reading files and computing callgraph...
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `which dialyzer`? I am wondering why dialyzer searches for code in `/usr/local/lib/erlang`. I would expect that `evm` places Erlang somewhere else, as it has to distinguish between versions. I have been using https://github.com/kerl/kerl to manage different OTP versions and never ran into a problem like this.

Comment: @evnu, 17.5: `$ which dialyzer
/usr/local/bin/dialyzer`, 19.2: `$ which dialyzer
/Users/7stud/.evm/erlang_versions/otp_src_19.2/bin/dialyzer`

Comment: @7stud I suspect there was a `.dialyzer_plt` already created with OTP 17.5 before you switched to 19.2, and `dialyzer` tried to update that one.

Comment: @juan.facorro, As I said in my question, I got dialyzer working with 17.5, then I switched to 19.2 and tried the same.  The error message even says: *the PLT /Users/7stud/.dialyzer_plt was built with an old version of Dialyzer*.  But what's the solution?  Delete the .dialyzer_plt file?  That seems like a pain because then won't I have to rebuild the plt every time I switch elrang versions?  Or, I guess I could rename the file to .dialyzer17.5_plt before switching versions.

Comment: Yes, deleting the files is the way to go. The simplest work around would be to build one `.plt` per Erlang version and name it appropriately, e.g. `.dialyzer.otp-17.2.plt`. Then pass that file into dialyzer.